# What happens to java Connection Pools, when fail-over occurs with Oracle (TAF)?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, failover

If i am using Apache DBCP Connection Pooling or JBoss provided datasource; along with Oracle Thick OCI Client which is configured to support TAF (transparent application failover):

**Question:**
What happens to the Connection Pool when fail-over occurs? 
Will it automatically refreshed/reset etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the JDBC Type 2 driver and TAF is enabled the pool should not even need to refresh. For the pool the connection is still there and not touched. If you have some uncommited changes as the failover happened then you could get some ORAs but after a rollback it will recover again.